# ASP.NET WEB API: If CORS is disabled, why I'm allowed to post to the web api from localhost?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Scenario:

CORS is disabled. API is hosted in Azure. Why I'm allowed to post to the web api from my machine, that, that I suppose is localhost domain? Can someone let me know if I have a complete misunderstanding of what CORS does?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

While CORS is configured on the server, it is up to the client to enforce it.

Most web browsers do enforce it, and fall back to the same origin policy if it is not enabled on the server.

If you make a request with an HTTP client like Postman, or code running in some other application, CORS is not a factor.